# Why isn't the part title vertically centered by default?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment

Using the `\part` command for the first time with the `\documentclass` *book*, I realized that the title of the part was not centered vertically and was higher on the page than it "should" be. With this MWE, I have a vertical space of about 60 mm at the top of the page and 113 mm at the bottom, i.e. almost double.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength\topskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

\part{My first part}

\end{document}
```

After looking at their definition, the `\part` and `\@endpart` commands can be mimicked (as far as vertical alignment is concerned) with this simple MWE below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength\topskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

\null\vfil
A\par
\vskip 20pt
A\par
\vfil

\end{document}
```

Why isn't the part title vertically centered? What elements "push" the title to the top of the page?

I realised that if I replaced the `\vfil` with `\vfill`, which is "stronger" than `\vfil`, I got a title that was vertically centered on the page (image and MWE below). Why isn't this the default behaviour?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength\topskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill
A\par
\vskip 20pt
A\par
\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why questions are always hard to answer for anybody but the author of the code, but from a composition point of view, elements look often more interesting and harmonic if they are not in the centre. For a written document, you will have the additional effect, that your readers start from the top of the page. Having to go all the way down to the centre of the page, will feel like a very long way.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thirds and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section for non centred arrangements.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I apologise if my question wasn't very clear, but it was more about why `\null\vfil ... some text ... \vfil` doesn't centre the content vertically as you'd intuitively expect by default. But something is "pushing" the title up the page.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had asked about the design :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part page is forced with a forced pagebreak, in your example by `\end{document}` which does `\clearpage` which does `\newpage`.

`newpage` is

```
\def \newpage {%
  \if@noskipsec
    \ifx \@nodocument\relax
      \leavevmode
      \global \@noskipsecfalse
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@inlabel
    \leavevmode
    \global \@inlabelfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak \@nobreakfalse \everypar{}\fi
  \par
  \ifdim\prevdepth>\z@
     \vskip -%
       \ifdim\prevdepth>\maxdepth
         \maxdepth
       \else
         \prevdepth
       \fi
  \fi
```

```
  \vfil
```

```
  \penalty -\@M}
```

so it adds `\vfil` to allow the forced page to be short.

Thus your example has one `\vfil` above the text and two below it, so is placed a third of the way down the page.

This isn't explicitly documented in the standard classes (most design decisions in those classes are not) but it appears to be by design.

Comment: Should we ask Leslie? ;)